# Reading string from a text file

Tags: c++, string

I edited my code, with the one Quentin gave me. So my problem is that I would like to use the function launched by the keyword in carac from a text file, and use the string right after carac in this function that is in an other file included.

```c++
for(std::string carac; fichier>>carac;)
{
    auto found = _map.find(carac);
    if(found != _map.end()
    {
        found->second();
        pile_double.afficher();
    }
}
```

Comment: (fr) Une pile est LIFO, une _file_ est FIFO. (en) stacks are LIFO, _queues_ are FIFO.

Comment: Well, you're in a loop, so `fichier >> carac` will be executed every time.

Comment: Yes, so I'm reading every string, but I'd like to enter a function when the string in carac is a key word (sorry not sure how to say it in english). And in the case carac is a key word, this launch a function from an included file where I can't read fichier (which is file in french tho)

Comment: If `carac` is a keyword, you want to then enter the name of a function and call it?

Comment: Ye with my map, when I type a keyword the function is called.

Comment: Is the name of the function inside `fichier`?

Comment: No, in fichier I'm only reading the keyword that will launch the function, and the string after that keyword is usually an int that I need to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <functional>

static std::map<std::string, std::function<void()>> gMap = {
    {"un",      []{ std::cout << "ein\n";    }},
    {"trois",   []{ std::cout << "drei\n";   }}
};

int main(int, char**)
{
    std::ifstream fichier("input.txt");
    if(!fichier.is_open())
        return 1;

    for(std::string carac; fichier >> carac;) {
        auto found = gMap.find(carac);
        if(found != gMap.end()) {
            found->second();
            pile_double.display();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I think this does what you want. Note that you should check the return from >> rather than eof(), otherwise you perform one too many iterations.

Comment: OK I'll try this. Also, maybe I explained it wrong, In my function from the map, so  {"un",      []{ std::cout << "ein\n";    }}, in your example, I'd like to basically std::cout << "carac+1", so use the next string from my text file. Is it possible since the function is in an other file ?

Comment: So if your files contains "one two", you want the function associated to "one" to be called and use "two" ?

Comment: Yes that's exactly it

Comment: It's totally possible, but your functions will take said string as parameter. Did you try and implement it from what I've written ?

Comment: Yes I tried, but I don't think it worked. I have some error like 'found' does not name a type

Comment: You should edit your question to reflect your updated needs, the modified code and that new problem.